# How do I access x-goog-hash response headers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm trying to access the md5 that returns from uploading file to Google Cloud Storage.
But, I can only get the other headers, not the `x-goog-hash` that contains the md5.

[image: Attached image of response headers]

```
async uploadVideo(uploadURL: string, file: any) {
    return axios
      .put(uploadURL, file, {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
        },
      })

      .then((response) => console.log(response))

      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error: " + error);
      });
  }
```

This is what the console.log shows:

```
{
    "data": "",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "",
    "headers": {
        "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
        "content-length": "0",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        "date": "Tue, 01 Mar 2022 09:22:11 GMT",
        "server": "UploadServer",
        "x-guploader-uploadid": "ADPycdvmU7_-9wqmePl5m_jzzdCWmr84AZwEbv2SJJ99kJLkq2eYzpQqrMaK4mHu_RiNVI3WzTkVH5Y"
    },
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        "method": "put",
        "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/.........
        "data": {}
    },
    "request": {}
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell due to the redactions in your screenshot but are those headers in response to the PUT request?

Comment: Yes, the headers are part of the PUT response.

Comment: I suppose that the problem is that the header with the same name appears multiple times.